# How to share values between jsp Expression Language and javascript?

Tags: java, javascript, spring

In request object I have `List<Integer> list`

How can I iterate over this list using JavaScript?

I want to know the value of list elements.

I haven't this list values on my page

Comment: Hi user, we need to know a little bit more about how your view is interacting with your server side layer. Do it uses AJAX to request the list? Or you are feeding the list to your view through a controller and want to convert it to a JavaScript data structure? Please show us some code.

Comment: You can't use JS to inspect/operate on server side objects. Use server side EL to inspect them.

Comment: Or you are feeding the list to your view through a controller and want to convert it to a JavaScript data structure?  yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See, Data which you are getting is Java object ie list in your case.

if you want to manipulate using that object, it would be better instead of sending java object from Server side, send JSON string of List. I mean convert you list to JSON string.

```
   var data = <%=request.getAttribute("objectFromServer") %>;
    for (key in data ) {
            //Work here as per your need.
    }
```

This is one way to do, you can also do using eL Expressions if manipulation with list is not much(as json way is very easy as per  me).

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script>
   var list = '<%= arrayList %>';
   for (var i=0; i<list.size(); i++) {
      var nextElement = list.get(i);
      // do something
  }
 </script>
```